# DidRecieveRemoteNotification not inwoked immediately when app in background

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification

I'm trying to use Apple push notifications. Everyting works fine except when app is in background.

The callback method `DidRecieveRemoteNotification` is sometimes not called immediately after notification is received. Sometimes it takes more then 5 minutes to be invoked. Is this standard behavior?

When the app is running in foreground callback method is called right after receiving notification. I would like the same behavior even when app is in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silent notifications will invoke their callback immediately when in the background as their purpose is to wake the app up for a short period of time.

In order to save battery, regular push notifications won't invoke the callback while in the background (unless your app is executing something else in the background). The callback will be called the next time the app is opened, whether from tapping the notification or otherwise.

This is not something you can fix, this is how the eco-system works. If you need your app to do something immediately, you will have to use silent notifications

Comment: Tried your suggestion with silent notifications but it behaves just the same. Sometimes its inwoked immediately sometimes it takes some time.

Comment: Ok, so after further investigation I found out there was another error preventing iOS from waking up my application. Now it works as intended with silent notifications. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for like half an hour and i tried to send a lot of notifications maybe like 50. Then it again stopped waking up the app immediatly after notification delivery

Comment: @DanielGlos how quickly did you send the 50? PushNotificaitons have no SLA. They can be delayed, they may never show up, only one is stored on apples servers if you are offline and the rest are deleted etc. What is the use case you are trying to achieve, you may need a websocket

Comment: When customer creates new order notification is sent and app should print order bill.   iOS documentation says "Apps that use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications may not always be woken up early to process future notifications." so maybe this is the case why it stops working after recieving several notifications

Comment: @DanielGlos yes. If you are trying to make an app that will always be on listening for events (perhaps you are building something for in a store like a point of sale app), then no PushNotifications are the wrong way to go. You will need to use a websocket between your backend and enable a background mode so that the connection can stay open in the background